# cannot install psycopg2 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I am trying to install `python3-psycopg2` as a part of `postgresql` installation, but I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-psycopg2 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.7~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I installed `python3.8` and configured `python3` link to it:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
```

But I still get the same error.

I have an `Ubuntu 18.04` OS.

Comment: You could install via pip: `python3 -m pip install psycopg2-binary`

Answer (score 8):

The `Psycopg2` library is built as a wrapper around `libpq` and mostly
written in C. It is distributed as a `sdist` and is built during
installation. For this reason it requires some `PostgreSQL` binaries and
headers to be present during installation.

Consider running these 2 commands:

```
sudo apt install python3-dev libpq-dev
```

The main goal of the command above is to provide all requirements for building `Psycopg2`.

Then:

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

You should have `psycopg2` installed and working now.

Comment: sudo apt install `libpq-dev` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

While the explanation of Gitau is very good. You can simply install the psycopg2 binary instead as mentioned by Maurice:

`python3 -m pip install psycopg2-binary`

or just

`pip install psycopg2-binary`

Answer (score 0):

Sometime psycopg2-binary is not a solution because other packages require for psycopg2 on their dependencies.

As cited above, you need to install some libs on ubuntu before install psycopg2.
For me, I had to install build-essential as well.

```
sudo apt install python3-dev libpq-dev build-essential
```

and then

```
pip install psycopg2
```